# AngularJS module 'myApp' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS. Although it is a simple problem, I have found similar error but cause was different.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I have index.html file:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Module example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"/>
</head>
<body>
    2 + 2 = {{2 + 2}}
</body>
```

my app.js file is:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

All files were loaded:
[image]

Could you help me guys to resolve this simple issue.

Comment: try <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"><script/> instead of <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

to:

```
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

your tag script is not closed right, it must be:

```
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Guy, you have forgotten to close your script tag ! And your html tag ! And your doctype !

Try :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Module example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    2 + 2 = {{2 + 2}}
</body>
</html>
```

And it will works ...

Take a look at https://validator.w3.org before asking here, please.